# Minimising two interdependent equations with least squares regression.

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, numerical-linear-algebra, least-squares, linear-regression

Originally, I had a set of points in three dimensional space that I was fitting using linear regression. So my model is

$$Y = \alpha A+ \beta B$$

where $Y = \{y_i\}$ is the dependent variable, and $A = \{a_i\}$ and $B = \{b_i\}$ are predictors, $i = 1,...,N$. However, now I would like to add another condition,

$$C = \frac{1 - \beta}{ \alpha - 1}$$

where the $ C = \{c_i\} $ are a property based on $A, B$. Note that I would like to use $\alpha, \beta$ derived from the previous equation.

If I understand my problem correctly, I'm trying to find an $\alpha$ and a $\beta$ subject to minimise these two values:

$$ \min(Y - \alpha A - \beta B) $$
$$ \min(C - \frac{1 - \beta}{ \alpha - 1}) $$

Is it possible to still use linear regression for this kind of problem? If yes, how should I go about it? If not, what tools should I be considering?

If it helps, I've been working in R, using `lm` and `predict.lm`.

Comment: Could specify $C$?

Comment: $c_i = \frac{a_i}{b_i}$

Comment: I am not sure I undertsand the question. Do you want to fit $$y=\alpha\, a+\beta \,b+\frac{1 - \beta}{ \alpha - 1} \frac ab$$

Comment: Given that C is linked to A/B, it should all be part of one single problem. If @ClaudeLeibovici's interpretation of your question is correct (also what I would say) then you'd have to solve
$$\min_{\alpha,\beta} \| Y - (\alpha A + \beta B + {1-\beta\over \alpha-1} C \|^2_2 $$
with the constraint that $c_i=a_i/b_i$. You could try to differentiate with respect to $\alpha$, $\beta$ to find extreme values (with no guarantees since your problem is not convex)